# image validation using Yup in react and showing the error when submitting the form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

This is my project in react with typescript and i am using formik and yup for validation.I want validation on image : should be jpg or png, and size should be less than 2MB.I tried other available answers but that doesn't work also i want to validate on submitting the form, for that i have used
validateOnMount: false,
validateOnBlur: false,
validateOnChange: false,
It is working fine with these options, but Is there any way to specify that i want to show the error when i submit the form?

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import girlImage from "../../images/girl_img.png";
import "./Signup.css";

function Signup() {
 const phoneRegExp = /^[6-9]\d{9}$/;

 const formik = useFormik({
   initialValues: {
     photo: "",
     name: "",
     email: "",
     phone: "",
     password: "",
     cpassword: "",
   },
   validationSchema: Yup.object({
     email: Yup.string().email("invalid email").required("required"),
     phone: Yup.string().matches(phoneRegExp, "Phone number is not valid"),
     password: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
     name: Yup.string()
       .min(15, "min 15 characters are required")
       .required("name is required"),
     cpassword: Yup.string().oneOf(
       [Yup.ref("password"), null],
       "Passwords must match"
     ),
   }),
   onSubmit: (values) => {
     console.log(values);
     formik.resetForm();
   },
   validateOnMount: false,
   validateOnBlur: false,
   validateOnChange: false,
 });
 return (
   <div className="signup">
     <div className="container">
       <div className="two-col-wrap">
         <div className="left-block">
           <h1 className="title">Signup</h1>
           <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} onReset={formik.handleReset}>
             <div className="form-control">
               <label htmlFor="photo" id="photo-label">
                 Photo +
               </label>
               <input
                 type="file"
                 id="photo"
                 {...formik.getFieldProps("photo")}
               />
               {formik.errors.photo ? <p>{formik.errors.photo}</p> : null}
             </div>
             <div className="form-control">
               <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
               <input
                 type="text"
                 id="name"
                 {...formik.getFieldProps("name")}
               />
               {formik.errors.name ? <p>{formik.errors.name}</p> : null}
             </div>
             <div className="form-control">
               <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
               <input
                 type="email"
                 id="email"
                 // name="email"
                 autoComplete="username"
                 // value={formik.values.email}
                 // onChange={formik.handleChange}
                 {...formik.getFieldProps("email")}
               />
               {formik.errors.email ? <p>{formik.errors.email}</p> : null}
             </div>
             <div className="form-control">
               <label htmlFor="phone">PhoneNo</label>
               <input
                 type="tel"
                 id="phone"
                 {...formik.getFieldProps("phone")}
               />
               {formik.errors.phone ? <p>{formik.errors.phone}</p> : null}
             </div>
             <div className="form-control">
               <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
               <input
                 type="password"
                 id="password"
                 // name="password"
                 autoComplete="new-password"
                 // onChange={formik.handleChange}
                 {...formik.getFieldProps("password")}
               />
               {formik.errors.password ? (
                 <p>{formik.errors.password}</p>
               ) : null}
             </div>
             <div className="form-control">
               <label htmlFor="cpassword">Confirm Password</label>
               <input
                 type="password"
                 id="cpassword"
                 // name="cpassword"
                 autoComplete="new-password"
                 // onChange={formik.handleChange}
                 {...formik.getFieldProps("cpassword")}
               />
               {formik.errors.cpassword ? (
                 <p>{formik.errors.cpassword}</p>
               ) : null}
             </div>
             <div className="buttons-container">
               <button className="submit-btn" type="submit">
                 submit
               </button>
               <button
                 className="reset-btn"
                 type="reset"
                 onClick={formik.handleReset}
               >
                 Reset
               </button>
             </div>
           </form>
         </div>
         <div className="right-block">
           <img src={girlImage} alt="girl" />
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 );
}

export default Signup;
```